# PHP Zip Files from an Folder - no error - no archive

Tags: php

Iam getting crazy with PHP 5.2x and "ZipArchive", the following code does not throw an error, every part returns true, but no ZIP File is created.

Does someone can see an error iam not seeing?

```
if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        $filename = time() . '.zip';
        $path = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../download/';

        $status = $zip->open($path . $filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);

        if ($status !== true) {
            $this->log->err('Cant create zipArchive!');
            return false;
        } 

        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if (!is_dir($file)) {
                if (is_readable($file)) {
                    if (!$zip->addFile($file)) {
                        $this->log->err('Cant add File to archive: ' . $file);
                    }
                } else {
                     $this->log->debug('Added file to archive: ' . $file);
                }
            }
        }

        closedir($handle);

        if (!$zip->close()) {
            $error = $zip->getStatusString();
            $this->log->err($error); 
            $this->log->err('Cant create archive..');
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Try to output `realpath($path . $filename)` to check that you don't a problem here. You could also try to output `is_writable(realpath($path))` to check the rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually add any file in your ZIP archive. It's the only reason you have no errors.

`is_readable($file)` always return `false`, and when it does `Added file to archive ...` is printed, probably because you misplaced your `else` block.

You have to add the folder to `$file`, in your case it should be `$directory`:

```
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if (!is_dir($directory . $file)) {
        if (is_readable($directory . $file)) {
           if (!$zip->addFile($directory . $file)) {
                $this->log->err('Cant add File to archive: ' . $file);
            } else {
                $this->log->debug('Added file to archive: ' . $file);
            }
        } else {
            $this->log->debug('File not readable: ' . $file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: damn :-) Sometimes i should stop coding after a while thanks!

Comment: @ArneRie It was not obvious at first, but I got it when printing `$zip->numFiles` :)